# Hide Admin Links from everyone

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using asp.net mvc with razor. How can I hide links which are only for admins?

Comment: How are you determining whether someone is an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a boolean property on your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    ... some other model properties
}
```

and inside your view:

```
@if (Model.IsAdmin)
{
    <!-- show the link that only administrators are supposed to see -->
    @Html.ActionLink("Do something very special", "Bar")
}
```

and of course inside the controller action rendering this view you would populate this view model:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        IsAdmin = User.IsInRole("Admin")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Obviously the Bar action which only administrators could invoke should be decorated with the `Authorize` attribute as well:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    ...
}
```